# Cannot connect to postgresql databse from django settings.py on localhost

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Forgive me as I this is my first django project using postgresql (version 11.8).  For now I just want to connect to a test database which I have set up locally using pgadmin4.  When I create the database I am not given the option to add a password, but when I run python manage.py migrate it is insisting on a password.  When I then set the password to "password" on pgadmin, django won't accept it.  It's probably something really obvious as I am quite new to Django, but I have tried searching and not found the answer to my problem. In settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'test1',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Last line of the error when I run python manage.py migrate:
    django.db.utils.OperationalError: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
Any help much appreciated.  Craig

Comment: Which OS you are using?

Comment: Hi - it's Windows.

Answer (score 0):

When you installed PgAdmin4 it asked you to create a password. This is for the superuser postgres, which is what you are trying to connect as. Use psql to connect to the database using the above settings and supply the password and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks for that.  So I have added the server password for postgres 11.  But now I have a new problem: django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "test1" does not exist.  I've also run this at command prompt: setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin".  It says "Success" but hasn't solved my problem.

Comment: Btw I am in a virtual environment.  Could that have anything to do with it?

Comment: The database is not running in a virtualenv so that should not be an issue. Do you have more then instance of Postgres running? What is the full command you are running when you get the error?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by removing the Postgresql 11 server and reinstalling it.